# Zend Framework 1 custom robots.txt in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, routes, robots.txt

I have the following .htaccess, and I'm trying to execute the /robots.txt in /public/robots.php.
I tried different ways, but my php script was not being executed...

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/html text/plain text/xml text/json application/json
</IfModule>

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_globals off
php_flag short_open_tag on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(ico|js|css|jpeg|jpg|png|bmp|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|xmlx|xml|pps|eml|txt|psd|flv|swf|fla|mp3|ttf|eot|svg|woff|zip)$ public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

How can I use a dynamic robots.txt, executing the /public/robots.php ?

Thx!

Comment: Exactly what result do you get when you request /robots.txt from a browser? Especially status code and any error output? Also, what result do you get if you request /public/robots.php directly?

Comment: robots.txt returns 404 not found. and robots.php returns 'Mensagem: No route matched the request'

Comment: I fixed this problem, I'll post my solution here

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with this htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "^robots.txt$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Now, I'm able to execute the public/robots.txt as a php script. So, inside my public/robots.txt I'm able to test which server I'm using and create a dynamic robots.

Now when accessing the mysite.com/robots.txt the output is generated by public/robots.txt, executed as a PHP script.